# how to fill php date from javascript keypress event

Tags: javascript, php, dateinterval

I want to add automatically dates from a php array using javascript keypress event. Here's part of my code:

**Date array:**

```
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime("2015-07-03"), new DateInterval('P1M'), new DateTime("2018-07-09"));
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dates[] = $date->format("M Y");
}
```

**Text input:**

```
<input type="text" id="jumlah" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="myFunction()" onkeypress="return hanyaAngka(event)"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to `echo` july 2015 if I input 1, august 2015 if I input 2, etc..

How can I do that?

This is what I've tried, but it's not working:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("jumlah").value;
        var i='<?php echo $dates[x];?>';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are aware that your Javascript runs in your browser and your PHP on your webserver and that they need to communicate somehow?

Comment: yes of course iam trying this function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("jumlah").value;
 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

Comment: if i input 1 in jumlah then in demo also 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you try to mix the server side and the client sides variables.

```
var x = document.getElementById("jumlah").value;
var i='<?php echo $dates[x];?>';
```

`x` will be a javascript variable, what you can not use in your php. `<?php echo $dates[x];?>` Won't know, what is the `x` on client side.

You need to use ajax. Send the `x` as a parameter to the `ajax.php`, and returns with propery item of the array.

Something like this:

```
$('#jumlah').on('keyup', function() {
    $.get('ajax.php', {x: $(this).val()}, function(response) {
         $('#demo').html(response)
    });
});
```

In php

```
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime("2015-07-03"), new DateInterval('P1M'), new DateTime("2018-07-09"));
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dates[] = $date->format("M Y");
}
echo $dates[$_GET['x']];
```

Answer (score 0):

As Florian said, you are mixing two things: back-end and front-end.

You should do something like this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var value = document.getElementById("jumlah").value,
            dates = <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?>;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dates[value];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `dates = <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?>;` Mixing languages is also an avoidable thing, and break clean code principles.